# Website Interface Translation Chrome Extension

Tags: localization, translation

I work with the [Process Street](http://process.st) website but my users are not speaking English. I've successfully made it RTL using the Chrome stylish extension. But is there also an extension which will allow me to translate the text of the menus, buttons, error messages, etc...  ? I see there are similar extensions for other website - the [Zoho Creator Language Patcher](https://forums.zoho.com/topic/chrome-extension-for-interface-localization-what-laguages-to-add) for Zoho, and the [Asana Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/asana-translate/mmmjfjdbamonmaajclfcpicaanaonlfc) for Asana, but it's only for one website. Is there something generic?